# rnbinom in R returns error that says optional argument is missing

Tags: r

I am trying to reset the default arguments in the `rnbinom` function with the following example code:

```
params <- c("size" = 1, "mu" = 1)
formals(rnbinom)[names(params)] <- params
rnbinom(n = 10)
```

It returns the following:

`Error in rnbinom(n = 10) : argument "prob" is missing, with no default`

If I set the defaults with this code:

```
params <- c("size" = 1, "prob" = .5)
formals(rnbinom)[names(params)] <- params
rnbinom(n = 10)
```

The function works correctly. The documentation specifies that you can set mu or prob with size. How is rbinom evaluating this function so that the order of arguments set with formals has an effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), a functional programming technique to set the arguments to a function.

It's not working in your example because the values are still missing: `formals` is simply setting the default value to use when the argument is missing. The R Internals manual discusses this behavior [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Missingness). So when the `rnbinom` function calls `if (!missing(mu))` (see the source code in A. Webb's answer), it evaluates to `FALSE` and skips to the `else` clause where it evaluates `probs` in the call to `.External(C_rnbinom, n, size, prob)` and cannot find it, throwing the missing error.

A. Webb's approach will work here but you should also consider the approach used in `functional::Curry()` ([package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/functional/index.html)).

Example:

```
    library(functional)
    rnbinom <- Curry(rnbinom, "size" = 7000, "mu" = 5)
    rnbinom(n = 100)
```

This will work for all functions that you might want to curry and not require a unique wrapper for each function or special missing conditionals.

Under the hood, `functional::Curry` is doing something similar to the wrapper in  A. Webb's answer but in a more generic way:

```
    function (FUN, ...) 
    {
      .orig = list(...)
      function(...) do.call(FUN, c(.orig, list(...)))
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the source for `rnbinom`

```
> rnbinom
function (n, size, prob, mu) 
{
    if (!missing(mu)) {
        if (!missing(prob)) 
            stop("'prob' and 'mu' both specified")
        .External(C_rnbinom_mu, n, size, mu)
    }
    else .External(C_rnbinom, n, size, prob)
}
```

Note how it checks for whether arguments were supplied with `missing`. Arguments that are defaults and not supplied still count as missing.

```
> f <- function(x=1) missing(x)
> f()
# [1] TRUE
```

You should consider just writing a wrapper rather than messing with the formals

```
> rnbinom <- function(n, size=1, mu=1) stats::rnbinom(n=n,size=size,mu=mu)
> rnbinom(n=10)
 [1] 0 3 1 1 0 0 1 0 2 1
```

Comment: Why does the second example work then? Also that wrapper function works for explicitly stating the arguments, but not when trying to make a generalized function for fitting distributions that have differing arguments. This snippet of code works well for named parameters:
    `params <- c("size" = 1, "mu" = 1)`

    `rfit <- function(n) {
    do.call(rweibull, c(list(n = n), params))
}`

Comment: I don't quite understand your second sentence. Can you edit your question to give an example of something you want to do where a wrapper doesn't seem to work?

Comment: In both cases, the check for whether the `mu` is supplied as part of the function call in the `if` condition is false, so control goes to the `else` branch. The `else` branch is the version expecting a `prob`, which is supplied as a default in the second case. I am not following the intended behavior you are wanting, but you could supply your own conditionals in the wrapper function, e.g. provide all arguments and your own missing conditionals w/ defaults.